# Effectively reconstructing all original 5-tuples from a subset of their respective 4-tuples

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let's take integer numbers from [1..36]. We can generate 376992 different (order is not important) five-number-combinations like (1,3,5,7,12), etc. Such five-number-combinations always have five distinct (unique) numbers. Each such five-number-combination always contains 5 four-number-combinations (like (1,3,12,7), etc.). All 376992 different (unique) five-number-combinations have 58905 different (unique) four-number-combinations. All these four-number-combinations also have all (four) distinct numbers - being a subset of a set with unique numbers.

**Five-number-combinations and four-number-combinations (tuple-4) always have 5 or 4 distinct (unique) numbers respectively. This is prohibited: (1,1,2,3,4) or (2,3,5,2)**

Then I take at random approximately half of those 58905 different four-number-combinations - let's call them "unused 4-tuples".

Finally I need to generate *all possible* five-number-combinations each being such that it always consists of 5 unused four-number-combinations. That is all five four-number-combinations within such five-number-combination are from the "unused 4-tuples" set.

Direct (brute-force) algorithm is like this: I take a set of n=28000 unused 4-tuples, generate all combinations from that set by k=5 (binomial(n,k)) and then check that all five 4-tuples in such combination give exactly five numbers from [1..36] (say, I add individual numbers from every 4-tuple [out of every five 4-tuples] into a set and then check if the set contains exactly five numbers). Having checked all possible combinations (of five 4-tuples) I have solved my task.

The only problem is that binomial(30000,5) = 143368518402340005600  :)))

Could you think of some math trick to somehow sieve and shortcut that process, or maybe a tip to a more clever algorithm?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:contest-math]? If you haven't already done so, please make yourself familiar with [our contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Sort the tuples lexicographically: always keep the items within in sorted order, so `{1,2,3,4}` is okay but `{1,2,4,3}` is not.

Similarly, sort the *list* of tuples lexicographically: `{1,2,4,5}` should come after `{1,2,3,6}` should come after `{1,2,3,5}`.

Now: Consider pairs of tuples with the same first three elements and different final element, `{a,b,c,d}` and `{a,b,c,e}`, with $d<e$.  We now need to search for `{a,b,d,e}`, `{a,c,d,e}`, and `{b,c,d,e}`.  If all three are there, then `{a,b,c,d,e}` is a valid 5-tuple.

This works relatively quickly: since the 4-tuples are sorted lexicographically, we have a block-diagonal-matrix-like structure of 4-tuple pairs to examine, so instead of 450 million-ish pairs, we get approximately 90000 pairs that we have to search for the last three of.  And that search goes quickly: once again, since they're sorted, we can find our targets by bisection.

Comment: --actually, though I haven't tried it, you might get even better results by performing a grouping operation: put each item into a bin based on its first three elements.